# CCSequence not waiting for action to finish before next one starts

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing a blackjack game using cocos2D.
Im using CCSequence a lot and in numerous places in my code have issues with it.
The problem I'm having is that one action is firing before the previous one is done running.
for example:

```
-(void)standButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self removeChildByTag:333];

    if ((splitNumber<3)&&(numberSplitHits>0))
    {
        [self removeChildByTag:333];
        splitNumber++;
        if ([[hands objectAtIndex:splitNumber]handTotal]==0)
            goto end;
        [self afterSpliting];
        [self addArrow];
        return;
    }

    end:
    [self removeChildByTag:333];
    [[BackgroundLayer sharedBackground]menuSetup:hand gamePhase:3];
    BJDrawnCard *holeCard = [dealerHand getFlippedCard];
    [holeCard flipCard];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:SND_DEAL_CARD];
    [self generateDealerHandDisplay];
    [self updateDealerHandScoreDisplay];
    id myCallFun1 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self                  selector:@selector(finishDrawingDealer)];
    id myCallFun2 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(checkWhoWonHand)];
    id myCallFun3 = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:[BackgroundLayer sharedBackground]    selector:@selector(menuSetup:gamePhase:)data:(void*)6];
    CCDelayTime *delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2];
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions:myCallFun1,delay,myCallFun2,myCallFun3 ,nil]];
}
```

so myCallFunc2 would start running before myCallFun1 finishes.
I have the same problem in other parts of my code when using CCSequence, actions would start in order but not wait for an action to finish before the next one starts.

Is there a better way to sequence actions, or maybe even a substitute to CCSequence?

here is the method that myCallFun1 calls:

```
-(void)finishDrawingDealer
{
if (dealerHand.handTotal<17)
{
drawnCard=[havila drawFromDeck];
 [drawnCard setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache     sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:drawnCard.imageFileName]];
 CCMoveTo *move =[self animateDealerCards:drawnCard andPosition:[self  dealerCardPosition]];
CCDelayTime *delay = [CCDelayTime
                      actionWithDuration:0.5];
[dealerHand getCard:drawnCard];

//Run the action

numDealerHits++;
[self performSelector:@selector(updateDealerHandScoreDisplay) withObject:nil    afterDelay:1.0];


if (dealerHand.handTotal<17) {
    id more = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishDrawingDealer)];


    [drawnCard runAction:[CCSequence actions:delay,move,delay,more,nil]];
} else {
    [drawnCard runAction:[CCSequence actions:delay,move,delay,nil]];
 }
if (dealerHand.handTotal>21)

    [self dealerBusted];
}
}
```

Comment: You should review your way of indenting the code.

Comment: How do you notice that myClassFun2 is called before myClassFun1 finishes? I suppose you're logging it or using the debugger. Please also post the code or whatever make you come with this conclusion.

Comment: What myClassFun1 does ? can you post implementation ?

Comment: `CCCallFunc` is an instant action.

Comment: Here is the myCallFun1 method:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from that the CCCallFunc actions are instantaneous. They don't care about how long a given selector takes to run, all they care about is calling that selector. After they have called their selector they have effectively finished their job and then the sequence moves onto the next action.

Instead what you can do is call the next method at the end of each method like follows. I also noticed you wanted a delay which you could do with a sequence and CCCallFunc.

```
- (void)finishDrawingDealer
{
    //Do your work that takes time

    //Once it has finished
    id callNextMethod = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(checkWhoWonHand)];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:2.0f], callNextMethod, nil];
    [self runAction:sequence];
}
```

Comment: Why not just schedule a selector using the `CCScheduler`, then? No need to run actions. Also, you should be using `CCCallBlock` instead of `CCCallFunc`, anyway, assuming you are on Cocos2D 2.x.

Comment: Yeah true, that would work as well. CCCallFunc works fine if you already have methods. The only one I don't like is CCCallFuncND as that doesn't work nice with ARC.

Comment: How would I use a CCScheduler?